# Recursividade - Porque estou entrando em um loop?

Tags: c, algoritmo, recursão, jogos, inteligência-artificial

Eu estou tentando implementar um algoritmo chamado minimax, mas estou encontrando problemas em efetuar sua recursividade, ele entra em um loop a qual não consigo identificar o porque. A profundidade do algoritmo deveria varias de acordo com as jogadas que são testadas, mas a profundidade que ocorre é: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... Ele deveria retornar e sair da profundidade 0, voltando para 1, e assim por diante, mas persiste no 0.

Por padrão a profundidade inicial será sempre 5.
A função `verificar_jogadas_possiveis()` serve para criar uma lista encadeada com todas as jogadas possíveis do player passado como parâmetro.

```
Jogadas *minimax(int tabuleiro[TAM][TAM], int depth, int Player, Jogadas* novaJogada){
    //Fiz esse trecho apenas para checar se o loop persiste
    printf("%d\n", depth);
    Sleep(100);
    // Copy the board for don't change it
    int i, j, copia[TAM][TAM];
    for(i=0; i<=9; i++){
        for(j=0; j<=9; j++){
            copia[i][j] = tabuleiro[i][j];
        }
    }

    copia[novaJogada->lin_dps][novaJogada->col_dps] = copia[novaJogada->lin_atual][novaJogada->col_atual];
    copia[novaJogada->lin_atual][novaJogada->col_atual] = 0;

    if(depth == 0){
        return novaJogada;
    }

    Lista_ia *Moves = inicializarLista();

    verificar_jogadas_possiveis(copia, Moves, Player);

    Jogadas *tmp;

    // Simulating the current Player 2 (Computer) move
    if(Player == 2){
        novaJogada->pontuacao = -9999;

        for(tmp = Moves->head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->prox){

            Jogadas *BestMove = minimax(copia, depth - 1, 1, tmp);

            if(BestMove->pontuacao > novaJogada->pontuacao){
                novaJogada->pontuacao = BestMove->pontuacao;
            }
        }
        LiberarMemoria(Moves);
        return novaJogada;
    }
    // Simulating the best Player 1 move
    else{
        novaJogada->pontuacao = 9999;

        for(tmp = Moves->head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->prox){

            Jogadas *BestMove = minimax(copia, depth - 1, 2, tmp);

            if(BestMove->pontuacao < novaJogada->pontuacao){
                novaJogada->pontuacao = BestMove->pontuacao;
            }
        }
        LiberarMemoria(Moves);
        return novaJogada;
    }
}
```

Alguém me ajudar a descobrir o erro?

Comment: acho que isso não é um erro. é apenas porque são varias jogadas em sequencia na profundidade 0; Mande exibir qual jogada ele esta realizando.

Comment: Mas ele nunca sai da profundidade zero, além do mais mesmo q haja várias em sequencia, ainda assim ele deveria terminar a menina q vai zerando a profundidade e ir verificando as demais. Vou ver qual jogada fica presa quando retorna

Comment: Eu descobri que na verdade, isso funciona sim!! Mas infelizmente demora cerca de 25 segundos para ele responder... Completamente inviavel, será q existe uma forma de "simplificar" esse codigo pra exigir menos processamento?

Comment: Procura por `minimax com poda`

Comment: Outra opção é refazer a estrutura de como é as structs do seu xadrez, para otimizar os metodos de geração de jogadas possiveis, que pelo que pude observar são um dos grande consumidores de tempo do seu xadrez.